# Where can I get Intel Display Drivers appropriate for my laptop?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers

I'm trying to update my Intel Display Drivers to solve a problem about cloning my display to an external one, but I'm having trouble with it.

**My hardware:**

Asus N65VZ with an Intel Core i7 (3rd gen), Intel HD Graphics 4000, and nVidia GeForce GT650m. It came with Windows 8 installed, which I've since upgraded to Windows 8.1 - that's when all the problems started appearing.

I use an HDMI cable to project my display to an HD TV.

**The Problem:**

Firstly, I'm only doing this because "Duplicate" display option from Win + P doesn't work, and instead, produces this:

[image]

I've tried downloading and installing official drivers from Intel, both version [15.33.5.64.3316](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=23323&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%208.1,%2064-bit*&DownloadType=Drivers) and version [15.33.8.64.3316](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?agr=Y&DwnldID=23405&lang=eng&OSVersion=Windows%208.1,%2064-bit*&DownloadType=Drivers), but they returned this *little gem*:

[image]

**What I tried:**

I uninstalled my nVidia Display Driver, and installed the latest one I could download. It didn't change anything.

I tried manually updating my Intel Display Driver by going into computer management:

[image]

However it tells me that I'me already updated.

[image]

I've uninstalled Intel Display Driver from the Control Panel, in preparation for installing the updated Intel driver (which failed, as noted above), as seen here:

[image]

Strangely, it still shows up in the Desktop's Right Click Menu.

[image]

Going to Asus' own website of course was a no-go - the drivers there are outdated, and were perhaps meant for Windows 8 only, if not Windows 7 only.

This is bugging me.

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: It's a laptop with an integrated and a dedicated graphic card. In order to make them work, you need specific drivers which can't be obtained from the official Intel or NVIDIA website, which only provide generic versions, and might not be compatible at all. The same usually applies to the Microsoft Update Catalog, which is queried when you let Windows automatically search for updated drivers. Keep in mind the "Windows has determined the driver software for your device is up to date" message can be misleading: it will be displayed even when no compatible driver was found at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't select to automatically search for a driver.

Click on `Browse my computer for drivers software`

[image]

Click on `Browse`

[image]

Find the extracted driver and select it:

[image]

If this doesn't work, click on "Let me pick from a list of device driver" and select "have disk" and point here to the **.inf** file and select the device manually.

**Source:**

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/97061-driver-install-device-manager.html

Comment: Tried that, thanks. Still tells me that the driver software is up to date - even though I uninstalled it.

Comment: ok, click on "Let me pick from a list of device driver" and select "have disk" and point here to the **.inf" and select the device manually. Does this work?

Comment: I went into the 'Graphics' Folder under Win64_15335, and found the kit5666.inf, which I hope is the one you're talking about. After the installer rebooted my computer, it started asking me if I wanted to load some Intel igtray / igfx stuff... where it didn't before. Anyway I can get rid of these? It's annoying, and slows down startup.  

It didn't solve the Display duplicate issue, but it now Intel Graphics show up in Control Panel, so thanks.

Comment: Use AutoRuns to remove the Intel program: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx

Comment: Thanks. That solved the annoying-pop-up-at-startup issue.

Answer (score -2):

You are right, the problem is all because of windows 8.1 upgrade. As windows 8.1 has still many known bugs,i recommend you to roll back to windows 8. You can do this by going to refresh option. I was also having the  display problems , and got solved by going back to windows 8.

Comment: (-1) totally offtopic post.

Comment: You may be on to something about going back to Windows 8 base, but I can barely stand this OS - I don't think I can stomach going back to Windows 8. I'm wondering though, just how much is the difference between 8 and 8.1 such that a driver working for 8 fails on 8.1.